# Encode JSON in order to create it as secret with Python k8s Client

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a big yaml file that I want to store as a secret in my kubernetes cluster. The following command succeeds:

```
k create secret generic values --from-file=my-values.yaml
```

But in my code, I want to use the k8s python client.
So I want to do something like this:

```
def make_k8s_client(kubeconig):
....

def create_secret(name, data, client_api):
    secret = client.V1Secret(
        api_version="v1",
        kind="Secret",
        metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=name),
        data=data,
    )

    client_api.create_namespaced_secret(namespace="default",
                                              body=secret)

k8s_api = make_k8s_client("path-to-kubeconfig")

with open("path-to/my-values.yaml") as f:
    values = yaml.load(f)
```

If I pass the yaml like this:

```
create_secret("mysecret", values, k8s_api)
```

I get this error:

```
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Secret in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.Data: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 0, error found in #10 byte of ...|pe\": \"abc\", \"def|..., bigger context ...|{\"apiVersion\": \"v1\", \"data\": {\"k8sType\": \"abc\", \"secret\": \"mysecret\", \"type\": \"mytype","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

If I pass the secret like this:

```
create_secret("mysecret", base64.urlsafe_b64encode(json.dumps(values).encode()).decode(), k8s_api)
```

I get this error:

```
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Secret in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.Data: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found \", error found in #10 byte of ...| \"data\": \"eyJrOHNUeX|..., bigger context ...|{\"apiVersion\": \"v1\", \"data\": \"eyJrOHNUeXBlIjogImF3cyIsICJnYXJkZW5lclNlY3JldCI6IC|...","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

How do I have to encode the json file in order to be able to pass it to the python k8s client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data contains the secret data. Each key must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.'. The serialized form of the secret data is a base64 encoded string, representing the arbitrary (possibly non-string) data value here ([1](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Secret.md)).

```
V1Secret(
    api_version="v1",
    kind="Secret",
    metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=name),
    data={
    'my-values.yaml': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(values).encode()).decode("utf-8")
     },
```

[How to create and use a Secret](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/v24.2.0/examples/notebooks/create_secret.ipynb)